# ¿Cómo agrupar una lista utilizando dos campos de tipo String y regresar la cuenta utilizando lambdas en Java 8?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo *lambdas* en *Java 8* pero me atore con este ejemplo que quiero realizar (capaz que no se pueda).

Tengo la siguiente lista (`resultado`), y quiero obtener una lista como lo comento en la sección de resultado esperado.

¿Cómo se puede hacer en *Java 8* con *lambdas* y su explicación?

No he podido resolverlo.

```
List<Caso> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"A","HP","WINDOWSXP"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"B","HP","WINDOWSXP"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"C","HP","WINDOWSXP"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"D","HP","WINDOWS10"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"E","HP","WINDOWS10"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"F","APPLE","ELCAPITAN"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"G","DELL","WINDOWS10"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"H","DELL","WINDOWS10"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"I","LINUX","FEDORA"));
resultado.add(new Caso(1,"J","LINUX","DEBIAN"));

// resultado esperado
// HP WINDOWSXP 3
// HP WINDOWS10 2
// APPLE ELCAPITAN 1
// DELL WINDOWS10 2
// LINUX FEDORA 1
// LINUX DEBIAN 1
```

Comment: hay varias formas pero... no hay informacion de la definicion de `Caso`, necesito saber que attributos o metodos tiene para ver que opciones hay. ademas de esto ya ah intentado algun metodo?

Comment: No le pongas resuelta, eso no es válido en esta plstaforma; ya tienes una respuesta aceptada con eso basta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu clase `Caso` es de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Caso {
    private Integer id;
    private String tipo;
    private String marca;
    private String sistema;
    // Constructores, getters y setters
}
```

Puedes utilizar dos veces el método `Collectors.groupingBy` primero para agrupar por `marca` y el segundo para agrupar por `sistema` con la diferencia que a este le añades la opción de que realice la cuenta (`Collectors.counting()`), el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
final Map<String, Map<String, Long>> result = resultado.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Caso::getMarca,
        Collectors.groupingBy(Caso::getSistema, Collectors.counting())));
```

Para mostrar el resultado utilizamos la variable `result` e iteramos sobre los resultados utilizando el método `forEach` el primero para recuperar el `Map` que el campo `marca` agrupado y el segundo para recuperar el `Map` que tiene la cuenta de la variable `sistema` también agrupada.

El código queda de la siguiente forma:

```
result
    .forEach((marca, sistemaCountMap) -> {
        sistemaCountMap.forEach((sistema, count) -> {
            System.out.println(String.join(" ", marca, sistema, count.toString()));
        });
    });
```

El resultado de lo anterior mostrará lo siguiente:

```
APPLE ELCAPITAN 1
LINUX DEBIAN 1
LINUX FEDORA 1
HP WINDOWSXP 3
HP WINDOWS10 2
DELL WINDOWS10 2
```

#### Referencias

1. [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)
2. [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: Creo que te falto ordernar por `Tipo` para que el resultado sea en el mismo orden de:  
`"resultado esperado"`.

Answer (score 3):

Partiendo del supuesto que la clase `Caso` sea Similar a lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Caso {

    private final int valor;
    private final String Marca;
    private final String letra;
    private final String OSvalue;

    public Caso(int i, String letra, String marca, String os) {
        this.valor = i;
        this.letra = letra;
        this.Marca = marca;
        this.OSvalue = os;
    }


    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return Marca;
    }

    public String getLetra() {
        return letra;
    }

    public String getOSvalue() {
        return OSvalue;
    }

    /**
     * Equals se le hace Override para que resultado.stream().distinct() 
     * funcione de la forma que se desea
     * notese que algunos atributos no son tomas en consideracion para equals
     */
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         if (obj != null && Caso.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
             final Caso other = (Caso) obj;
             //if it is the same reference dont bother... 
             if (this == obj) return true;
             if ((valor == other.valor)&&Marca.equals(other.Marca)&&OSvalue.equals(other.OSvalue)) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 47 * hash + this.valor;
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.Marca);
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.OSvalue);
        return hash;
    }

}
```

con lo anterior claro y sabiendo:

> ```
> List<Caso> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "A", "HP", "WINDOWSXP"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "B", "HP", "WINDOWSXP"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "C", "HP", "WINDOWSXP"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "D", "HP", "WINDOWS10"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "E", "HP", "WINDOWS10"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "F", "APPLE", "ELCAPITAN"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "G", "DELL", "WINDOWS10"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "H", "DELL", "WINDOWS10"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "I", "LINUX", "FEDORA"));
> resultado.add(new Caso(1, "J", "LINUX", "DEBIAN"));
> ```

para obtener el resultado deseado se procede:

```
resultado.stream().distinct().forEach(unique -> {
System.out.printf("%s %s %d %s", unique.getMarca(),unique.getOSvalue(), resultado.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(unique)).count(),System.lineSeparator());
    });
```

a lo cual `resultado.stream()` nos da un stream el cual filtramos los valores "unicos"  que son definidos por comparacion utilizando `Caso.equals` sobre el `stream` de unicos se hace un `.forEach` donde en cada uno ejecutamos un `Predicate` el cual se tiene como parametro la referencia `unique` (del valor unico).

este funciona de la siguiente forma:

Por cada "valor unico" filtre(incluya) todos los valores que en resultados sean igual a `unique` (`resultado.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(unique))`), luego cuente cuantos hay.(`.count()`) y luego imprima un mensaje que incluye el valor.

(`System.out.printf(<formato>,unique.getMarca(),unique.getOSvalue(), <el conteo filtrado de unique>)`)

el resultado:

```
HP WINDOWSXP 3 
HP WINDOWS10 2 
APPLE ELCAPITAN 1 
DELL WINDOWS10 2 
LINUX FEDORA 1 
LINUX DEBIAN 1
```

Nota: si no se desea alterar el `Equals` se puede crear un Predicate especial el siguiente se utilizaria 1 solo filtro:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

referencias:

[Java 8: Preferred way to count iterations of a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790784/java-8-preferred-way-to-count-iterations-of-a-lambda)

[How to override equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

[Lambda Predicate](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.function/Predicate/index.htm)

[Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)